# How does one store the information to be able to plot the error vs epochs in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I wanted to plot the error vs the number of epochs in keras. To do that I found a really useful post [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/). It works like a charm locally but if I want to run my scripts in some remote GPU/cluster then its not as useful because I need to send myself the data to be able to actually make the plots. Is there a way to run something similar but store the errors in some file/csv/json anything and then be able to send that to myself with standard tools like rysnc/scp/dropbox?

Right now the only idea I had was to pickle the file and then send it to myself and unpickle it but it doesn't work at all. I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "store_data.py", line 71, in <module>
    pickle.dump( history, open( "history.p", "wb" ) )
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed
```

Is there a different way to do it using Keras and python? I just need to be able to store this type of data so that I can send it to my local computer somehow.

---

Currently my totally reproducible error can be done as follow:

store_data.py

```
# Visualize training history
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.utils import np_utils

import numpy
import pickle

print('start visualization example')

#params
nb_classes = 10

data_augmentation = False

units_single_layer = 10
actication_func = 'relu'
actication_func = 'sigmoid'

nb_epoch = 3
batch_size = 64
#optimizer = 'adam'
optimizer = 'rmsprop'

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
# The CIFAR10 images are RGB.
img_channels = 3

# The data, shuffled and split between train and test sets:
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],32*32*3))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0],32*32*3))
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

# create model
print('\n ---- Singled Layer Model ----')
print('units_single_layer: ', units_single_layer)
print('actication_func: ', actication_func)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units_single_layer, input_shape=(32*32*3,)))
model.add(Activation(actication_func))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Compile model
print('\n ---- Optimizer ----')
print('optimizer: ', optimizer)
print('batch_size: ', optimizer)

print('')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
#history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
          shuffle=True)

pickle.dump( history, open( "history.p", "wb" ) )
```

and to plot it:

plot.py

```
# Visualize training history
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.utils import np_utils

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy
import pickle

history = pickle.load( open( "history.p", "rb" ) )

# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Also, if ur having issue with matplot lib due to framework builds just use the virtual env that already solves that problem for you with:

```
python3 -m venv <my-virtual-env-name>
```

http://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html#virtualenv

http://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html

http://matplotlib.org/faq/virtualenv_faq.html

the `-m venv` uses python3’s implementation of virtualenv, and that implementation makes python a framework.

Comment: Has my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

Try pickling only loss dictionary:

```
pickle.dump( history.history, open( "history.p", "wb" ) )
```